# Update multiple Columns from multiple tables from the result of Nested SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-update, subquery

I have this query up and running and it gives the absolute correct result. I have 4 tables in total. `Table1` , `Table2` , `Table3` and `Table4`. The resultant query gives the result by joining 3 different tables.

Now the problem is that I have to 'update' 1 column PER row from each table.  I am unable to dig the solution.  I'm stuck from 2 days on the same problem, any help would be deeply appreciable :)

```
SELECT TempID,
       custom,
       STATE,
       orgUnit,
       displayName ,
       stateCust ,
       consumer.bol_is_active AS stateConsumer
FROM
  (SELECT TempID,
          custom,
          STATE,
          cust.id_orgunit AS orgUnit,
          cust.str_display_name AS displayName,
          cust.bol_is_active AS stateCust
   FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT CA.ID_CUSTOMER AS TempID ,
                      ca.str_value AS custom,
                      ci.bol_is_active AS STATE
      FROM Table1 CA
      JOIN Table2 CI ON CA.ID_CUSTOMER = CI.ID_CUSTOMER AND CI.ID_CUSTOMER = '11667312'
      WHERE CA.STR_VALUE='Customer'
        AND ci.bol_is_active ='N')
   JOIN Table3 Cust ON TempID = cust.id_customer)
JOIN Table4 consumer ON TempID = consumer.id_customer;
```

I want to update the value of `STATE` , `statuCust` and `stateConsumer`.Please help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as three separate `UPDATE` statements, since the values are in different tables.  The three updates can be wrapped in a transaction so they are all done as a single operation.

The `WHERE` clause for each `INSERT` statement will look similar to the join and where clauses on the select, so the row to be updated matches the row shown by the select statement.  I do not have time now to work out each INSERT statement, hopefully this points you in the right direction, and I will try to update this answer with more detail later.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ;

-- Update STATE
UPDATE Table2 SET bol_is_active WHERE ... ;

-- Update stateCust
UPDATE Table3 SET bol_is_active WHERE ... ;

-- Update stateConsumer
UPDATE Table4 SET bol_is_active WHERE ... ;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. U made one thing clear which gave me right direction i.e i have to use 3 update statements rather then 1. i now have successfully executed 3 different update statements :)